# Amazon appflow creating new files (partitioning) every time a Salesforce flow is run, but I want to overwrite previous flow's file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-quicksight, amazon-appflow

Is there a way to overwrite the data from a previous flow's output? I want to run a flow daily to pull in data from Salesforce and export into a csv, but do not need to keep yesterday's csv output at all. This would also help referencing the data in Lambda functions/Quicksight, otherwise the most up to date data file keeps changing.

Is this something that can be done in the Appflow tool or through Lambda?

Tried using all the settings in Appflow and de-selecting anything under the aggregate menu, but "Execution Id" keeps getting auto-selected, which partitions out the output of each flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use S3 you can set a lifetime rule for a key.